# WP7 Automatic scrolling text in a textbox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, smartphone

I want the texts that go beyond the screen scrolls horizontally ..
Can you help me? (I'm sure)

[ScreenShoot](http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/5636/screenshot001dv.png)

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking. Do you want them to animate to reveal the text that extends beyond the right-hand edge of the screen?

Comment: I want the text move from left to right if it is larger than the width of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, having content that scrolls both horizontally and vertically is a bad idea as it makes it harder for the user to navigate the content.

That said, you can enable something be able to be scrolled horizontally by putting it in a `ScrollViewer` and setting the `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility`.

Comment: Ok, it's true that if all my textboxs start dancing it would give a disagreeable effect.